# How do you refer to a function's environment in R?

Tags: r, environment

I am getting the following error because I believe a `clusterExport()` (`parallel` package) I'm doing is referring to the wrong environment:

```
Error in get(name, envir = envir) : object 'simulatedExpReturn' not found
```

I am getting this in a function and specifically at the `clusterExport()` line of this part:

```
  simulatedExpReturn = list()

  # Calculate the number of cores
  no_cores <- detectCores()

  # Initiate cluster
  cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)

  clusterExport(cl, c("simulatedExpReturn",
                  "covariance",
                   "numAssets",
                   "assetNames",
                   "numTimePoints-lag",
                   "stepSize"), envir = environment(Michaud1998MonteCarlo))
```

`covariance`, `numAssets`, `assetNames`, `numTimePoints-lag`, and `stepSize` are all passed into the function. I have also tried `envir = envir` and `envir = .GlobalEnv` and neither worked.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: When I use `clusterExport` I say `clusterExport(cl,"object",envir=environment())` and it works just fine. I can't tell you why, which is why this is a comment ;-)

Comment: Well `envir = envir` would only work if you actually had a variable `envir`.

Comment: Im guessing your `simulatedExpReturn` is defined within a function, hence `.GlobalEnv` wouldnt work. The `environment()` seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

A simple example of passing variable via its name to another function:

```
print.variable.from.env <- function (x,e) { cat("Echoing", get(x, envir = e)) }

my.f <- function()
{
    my.local <- "my local "
    print.variable.from.env("my.local", environment())

}

my.f()
```

if you run it, it will simply print

```
Echoing my local
```

i.e. by passing the environment to `print.variable.from.env`, the function is able to get access to the varialbe given by its name in `x`

And one more example:

```
print.variable.from.env <- function (x,e) { cat("Echoing", get(x, envir = e), "\n") }

my.f <- function()
{
    my.local <- "my local "
    print.variable.from.env("my.local", environment())
    print.variable.from.env("global.variable", parent.env(environment()))
}

global.variable <- "global"

my.f()
```

This shows the access to "global.variable" from function's parent env.
When executed it'll print

```
Echoing my local  
Echoing global
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a scoping problem, the `clusterExport` function is searching for your objects in the specified environment, and exports them to each processor's child environment. It does not search the `.GlobalEnv` where you have defined `simulatedExpReturn`.

This is why the following returns `1` and not an empty list:

```
> Michaud1998MonteCarlo <- new.env()
> simulatedExpReturn = list()
> assign("simulatedExpReturn", 1, envir = Michaud1998MonteCarlo)
> 
> # Calculate the number of cores
> no_cores <- detectCores()
> 
> # Initiate cluster
> cl <- makeCluster(no_cores)
> 
> clusterExport(cl, c("simulatedExpReturn"), envir = Michaud1998MonteCarlo)
> clusterCall(cl, function() simulatedExpReturn)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 1

[[4]]
[1] 1
```

To resolve, simply assign the value to the environment before running the `clusterExport`:

```
assign("simulatedExpReturn", list(), envir = Michaud1998MonteCarlo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even simpler, if you just want to access the caller's environment:

```
print.variable.from.env <- function (x) { 
    cat("Echoing", get(x, envir = parent.frame())) 
}

my.f <- function() {
    my.local <- "my local "
    print.variable.from.env("my.local")
}

my.f()
```